# How can I properly test compatibility of a replacement led on a pcb?

Tags: pcb, test, test-equipment

I am looking to replace an led on this board, but I am unsure of what this current led's specs are in terms of what amperage and voltage are used by the led. I am curious what ways I can test to make sure that the new LED I am wanting to switch with, wont damage the board.

I believe I can do some tests with the LED itself using a multi-meter for amperage and voltage, but not sure what settings to use.  Are there other tools/ways to test?  Is there a way to get a spec sheet somehow?

Is it possible to test the board itself to find out what amperage levels it could handle to make sure that the  led's amperage draw wouldn't damage the board? I would assume that too much current "could" damage the board, but in this case probably not since led draws are tiny(60 mA on the new one at full white brightness). I know my power supply can handle the led, but figured I should ask, just in case the board would break.

I'm a bit new to this field, so I appreciate any guidance to learning more about this, and any resources are appreciated, thanks you.

Comment: To a large extent, the board decides which current it will force through the LED, not the other way around.

Comment: Show a picture.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev so there wouldn't be any danger issues from current then, and the led would just dim?

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a indicator LED, you can probably replace it with any LED of the same color.  Just about any LED, unless in a very tiny case, can handle 20 mA.  Circuits that light indicator LEDs generally run them at less than that, especially if the LED isn't intended to be seen in sunlight.

LED forward voltage depends on the color, so as long as the replacement LED has the same color, the circuit shouldn't care.

Basically, replace with the same package and color, and you'll probably be fine if this is a indicator LED.

Comment: I assume it would be an indicator led, but I am looking to replace it with a color changing led.  I wanted to connect it to the circuit, because the led blinks, so I wanted to have that continue through which I'm assuming is the power, and the circuit just cuts power to make it blink?

Comment: @Xao: Don't replace with a "color changing" LED if a fixed color was in there before and you don't know what the circuit is doing.  Yes, to blink a LED, the circuit simply turns off the power to the LED during the blink off phase.

Comment: I figured that as long as the data pin (what tells it to change color) gets set from an external source, and the voltage usage is the same from the circuit, while the current isn't too high, that there wouldn't be an issue?  What else does the circuit need to know other that the power needed?  I'm also curious if there is any issue with "ground?"  Are all grounding points similar, or are some "Better" or "needed" for certain things?  I would assume ground is ground, but maybe not?